# A flag (indicator) that shows for each row which conditions was used to select it

Tags: postgresql, condition

Suppose I have the table `foo`. I want to filter the rows of this table using different conditions (`cond_1`, `cond_2`, ..., `cond_n` - **the order is important**) combined in a disjunction, i.e.:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE cond_1 OR cond_2 OR ... OR cond_n;
```

1. Is it possible (in PostgreSQL 13) to distinguish for each row which condition `cond_i` was used to select it? Since I stated that the order is important the question may be reformulated as - I want to know the first `cond_i` that selected the row, for each row.

Now consider that I have in `foo` a column for this purpose, e.g. `selected_by`.

2. Is it possible to distinguish for each row which condition `cond_i` was used to select it and store it in `selected_by`? (the same as 1st question but for an UPDATE statement)

Two things are important: the order of conditions (as it was highlighted earlier); performance (i.e. table `foo` may have many rows, the number of conditions is small, up to 5-10).

Comment: Might a row appear because it matched more than one condition? What do you want in that case?

Comment: yes its possible, but I want to know only the first matching condition

Answer (score 3):

If your conditions are mutually exclusive (you you only care about matching the first of an order you control) then you could get away with a single column:

```
SELECT *,
  CASE 
    WHEN name = 'meatfeast' THEN 'name' 
    WHEN diet = 'vegan' THEN 'diet' 
  END as reason_for_appearing
FROM
  pizza
WHERE
  name = 'meatfeast' OR diet = 'vegan'
```

You repeat your where conditions as individual clauses of a case when, (in the order you care about them)

---

If they aren't mutually exclusive and you want to know all the reasons why it might have matched you'll either need multiple columns ..

```
SELECT *,
  CASE WHEN name = 'john' THEN 'yes' END as because_of_name,
  CASE WHEN city = 'Chicago' THEN 'yes' END as because_of_city
FROM
  person
WHERE 
  name = 'john' OR city = 'chicago'
```

.. unless you want to get really involved with a huge case when of all the conditions combinations (which is 2^N, as I'm sure you can imagine)

Or you might alternatively do some kind of concat you can pick apart programmatically or the user can read

```
SELECT *,
  CONCAT(
    CASE WHEN name = 'john' THEN 'name' END,
    CASE WHEN city = 'Chicago' THEN ' city' END 
  ) as because_of
FROM
  person
WHERE 
  name = 'john' OR city = 'chicago'
```

I suppose it rather depends on what you want to do with it after

Comment: How `CASE...WHEN` impacts performance (if it does)?

Comment: That's one of those things that you really need to measure for your own context..

Answer (score 0):

You may calculate conditions mask (binary representation, for example):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (id INT, val INT);
> INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *, 
>        (id=1 AND val=1)::INT + 2 * (id<val)::INT + 4 * ((id+val)!=3)::INT conditions_mask_bin,
>        (id=1 AND val=1)::INT + 10 * (id<val)::INT + 100 * ((id+val)!=3)::INT conditions_mask_dec
> FROM test
> WHERE (id=1 AND val=1)
>    OR (id<val)
>    OR ((id+val)!=3);
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val | conditions_mask_bin | conditions_mask_dec
> -: | --: | ------------------: | ------------------:
>  1 |   1 |                   5 |                 101
>  1 |   2 |                   2 |                  10
>  2 |   2 |                   4 |                 100
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=91682aa1678348a93852b66bb93a4100)*

Answer (score 0):

> the order is important) combined in a disjunction, i.e.:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE cond_1 OR cond_2 OR ... OR cond_n;
```

SQL operator "OR" does not do short circuit evaluation, so you won't be able to get the order. That's not really a problem though (see below).

Create example table:

```
create table foo as select n, random() a, random() b from generate_series(1,100000) n;
create index foo_a on foo(a);
create index foo_b on foo(b);
vacuum analyze foo;

explain select * from foo where a<0.001 or b<0.001;
```

This uses a bitmap index scan which is what we want. Now, to know which condition was used to select the row and **still use the indices** for speed, here's an example:

```
select * from (
    select *, a<0.001 cond1, b<0.001 cond2 from foo
) x where cond1 or cond2;
```

This returns the results of the boolean conditions in columns cond1, cond2. And postgres pushes the WHERE predicates into the subquery, which makes it use indices.

```
   n   |           a            |           b            | cond1 | cond2
-------+------------------------+------------------------+-------+-------
   708 |  0.0007290283008281051 |     0.5581544416923094 | t     | f
   999 |    0.05462208162814264 |  0.0001475405957194198 | f     | t
  1091 |     0.5386926978073099 |  0.0008352984591510904 | f     | t
  1337 |     0.9837970597728862 | 0.00043209987424575047 | f     | t
  1775 |     0.8604698247282592 |  0.0008855919256234301 | f     | t
```

Then depending on how you want the info returned about what condition was matched, you can put that into a subquery again, and:

```
select n,a,b,
array_position(ARRAY[cond1,cond2],true) as which_cond
from (
    select * from (
        select *, a<0.001 cond1, b<0.001 cond2 from foo
    ) x where cond1 or cond2 )y;

   n   |           a            |           b            | which_cond
-------+------------------------+------------------------+------------
   708 |  0.0007290283008281051 |     0.5581544416923094 |          1
   999 |    0.05462208162814264 |  0.0001475405957194198 |          2
  1091 |     0.5386926978073099 |  0.0008352984591510904 |          2
  1337 |     0.9837970597728862 | 0.00043209987424575047 |          2
  1775 |     0.8604698247282592 |  0.0008855919256234301 |          2
  2966 |  0.0009486625430277229 |     0.8721009112992277 |          1
```

You can use any of the other answers' code to determine which condition matched, depending on what you want. The important point is to apply this logic **after** the rows have been selected and the indices used. If you hide the conditions inside CASE statements or other stuff, then postgres won't be able to understand that it can actually use indices.

```
 Bitmap Heap Scan on foo  (cost=10.10..464.09 rows=189 width=24) (actual time=0.126..0.680 rows=193 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((a < '0.001'::double precision) OR (b < '0.001'::double precision))
   Heap Blocks: exact=180
   ->  BitmapOr  (cost=10.10..10.10 rows=189 width=0) (actual time=0.049..0.051 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on foo_a  (cost=0.00..5.07 rows=103 width=0) (actual time=0.026..0.026 rows=107 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (a < '0.001'::double precision)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on foo_b  (cost=0.00..4.94 rows=86 width=0) (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=86 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (b < '0.001'::double precision)
 Planning Time: 0.349 ms
 Execution Time: 0.752 ms
```